# How can I have accounts be part of a specific ASP.NET Identity Role straight from the register page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity

So I am following this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/#create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

What I want to do is make it so that when you register for a new account, you can have a field where a type of role is entered. In this case "canEdit" so when you create the account it has the role. I could only make the account manually from visual studio using the seed database method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly what you want ,  but what I get that you want to add users based in roles ? 
In this case : this tutorial can help you : 
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security